# Using signals in django while extending user model

Tags: python, django, model, signals

Basically I have 2 models that are 1 to 1 related with User model,

First model in `Employee` and second one is `Customer`.

I am also using signals for updates

```
#Signal functions inside each model
@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
    def create_customer(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
        if created:
            Customer.objects.create(user=instance)

@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def update_customer(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created == False:
        instance.customer.save()
```

When I register a user it gets duplicated both in customer and employee. Is there a way to prevent this?

Comment: **Tool tip** there is also 2 functions with name update_employee and create_employee.

Comment: Please *don't* use signals: https://www.django-antipatterns.com/antipattern/signals.html